# PHP Laravel - MSSQL - WhereBetween and Where

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I am trying to select records from my MSSQL database, with below parameters:

- Column 'first_etd' must be between two dates
- Column 'car_id' must not be the same as the current `$carId` variable.

This is my code:

```php
$carId = 47;
$from = Carbon::now()->subWeeks(2)->startOfWeek()->toDateString();
$to = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(4)->endOfWeek()->toDateString();

$consols = Consol::with(['car'])
                   ->where('car_id', '!=', $carId)
                   ->whereBetween('first_etd', [$from, $to])->get();
```

The above variable `$consols` returns no results.

If I remove the `->where('car_id', '!=', $carId)` from the statement, I successfully get results.

All the records in my database currently have `NULL` in the `car_id` column:

[image]

I have also tried to change the `!=` operator to `<>` without any luck.

Comment: Instead of `->toDateString();`, does it work with `->format('Y-m-d')` (i.e. the format in your DB?)

Comment: could you try `->whereNotIn('car_id', [$carId])`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't believe it is the dates that are the issue. If I remove the `where` clause, it finds both records.

Comment: @UzairRiaz That doesn't work either, unfortunately :(

Comment: Yeah, and `->toDateString();` returns it in the same format as `->format('Y-m-d')` (my bad, I thought it was different). I recall there being some caveats for dates between in Laravel, but I don't recall what it is at the moment. I'll keep checking.

Comment: Oh, sidenote, what is the datatype of `first_etd` in your database? `datetime`, `date` or `varchar`?

Comment: @TimLewis It's `date`

Comment: Hmm... I can't replicate this. `Model::whereBetween('date_column', [Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->toDateString(), Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->toDateString()])->get()` returns 14 records, adding a `where('id', '!=', $id)` lowers that to 13... `date_column` is a `date`, like yours, and tried with `->format()` and `->toDateString()`...

Comment: Is that using MySQL? I am using MSSQL (sqlrv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is not a fix to the SQL statement itself, but more a fix to my problem.

As said in my OP, I can find the two records if I remove the `where()` method. I figured I could start by getting the records, that's between my two dates and then do the `where()` filtering on the result collection.

This works:

```php
//Get the records from the database, that's between two dates.
$consols = Consol::with(['car'])->whereBetween('first_etd', [$from, $to])->get();

//Now $consols is a Laravel collection, so I can use the where() method here.
$consols = $this->consols->where('car_id', '!=', $carId);
```

Above successfully returns the two records.